# Anidar un array con bucle Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucles

Me encuentro con la necesidad de cambiar la estrucura de un array. Si tengo el siguiente array `let array1= [1,2,3,4,5]` debo anidar cada elemento asi:

```
[{index:1,value:[
  {index:2,value:[
    {index:3,value:[
      {index:4,value:[
        {index:5,value:[]}]}]}]}
]}]
```

he intentado con map asi:

```js
let array1= [1,2,3,4,5]

let result= array1.map((e)=>{
return {index: e, value: e}
})

console.log(result)
```

Pero el resultado no sera anidado. Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede reducir el arreglo desde la derecha e ir anidando el contenido

```js
let array1= [1,2,3,4,5]

const nested = array1.reduceRight((acc, curr, index) => [{index: index + 1, value: acc}] ,[])

console.log(nested)
```